# Format a date in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, formatdatetime

How can i use the format methode in the Class DateTime in PHP and take some format like :

**'Y-m-d H:i'** or just the date **'Y-m-d'**.

this my code and i putted a picture what i take when i do the dump :

```
    $thisday = new \DateTime(); // I want to take the system date is it ok this instruction ?

    $thisday->format('Y-m-d');

    dump($thisday);
    die();
```

How can i take just the 2016-04-21 ?

Or take the date, hour and minutes ?

[image]

Comment: ->format returns a string.

Comment: Hint: You're asking for a value but never saving it in a variable.

Comment: Is it really so hard to RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: What you are looking for is the return value of `DateTime::format()`. So: `$formattedString = $thisday->format('Y-m-d'); dump( $formattedString );`.

Comment: Decent Dabbler your answer is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) does not transform the original `DateTime` object into your formatted result, it simply returns your formatted result, which you are not assigning to anything. You need to assign

`$thisday->format('Y-m-d');`

to a new variable, and use that.

Comment: yes thank you like the answer of Decent Dabbler i must put it in a new variable because it is a string not an object :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result a variable. `DateTime::format` is returning the value, not changing the object itself

```
$str = $thisday->format('Y-m-d');
dump($str);
```